# How to set scope variable value in angularjs template

Tags: angularjs

I want to set value when query textbox is empty.
I want to do like this:

```
$scope.flag=0;
```

This is query textbox:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" />
```

When user types something, I set $scope.flag=1 in js file.
Hope you catch my problem. Please do needfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.** I did it in this way:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" /> 
    {{query=='' ? flag=0 : flag=1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" />
            {{ flag }} 
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.flag=0;

      $scope.search = function() {   
         $scope.flag= $scope.query.length >0 ? 1:0;
      }
});
```

Comment: I dont want to do it in js file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ng-init directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-init="flag=0" ng-change="search()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$scope.search = function () {
    if ($scope.query.length) {
        $scope.flag = 1;
    } else {
        $scope.flag = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to do it in js file.